# Dynamically add page numbers in android

Tags: android, web-services, android-layout, pagination

I am stuck with an issue in my project.The need is to show all data fetched from server using webservices.I successfully get data from server using json.but i want to show data on screen in tabular format 50 records at a time.Please suggest me how to do this or if you can guide me through a better way to implement paging in android.

The code of paging is here :

[Implement Pagination on tab layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736458/implement-pagination-on-tab-layout)

and the function i use to append rows dynamically to tablelayout is :

```
private void appendRows(TableLayout table, String[] data) {
        int rowSize = data.length;
        int colSize = (data.length > 0) ? 1 : 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < rowSize; i++) {
            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            for (int j = 0; j < colSize; j++) {
                String[] rowVal = null;
                rowVal = data[i].split(",");
                for (int k = 0; k <= rowVal.length - 1; k++) {
                    TextView c = new TextView(this);
                    c.setText(rowVal[k]);
                    c.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                    c.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
                    row.addView(c);
                }
            }
            table.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams());
        }
    }
```

Please guide me I need to show hyperlink page numbers at the bottom of my window as shown in google

Answer (score 0):

[This might be of some help](http://paulononaka.wordpress.com/2011/03/19/how-to-implement-a-paging-feature-in-android/). Its a tutorial for pagination. [Here is the source code.](https://github.com/paulononaka/Android-PaginationLayoutSample)

I have had similar requirement like yours and I normally use the listview for it. Due to the recycling of views it is a lot more efficient than using a table layout.

You can create a custom adapter where you always return the size as 50+1, 100+1. So in your onItemClickListener you can check if the row position is more than the items, if so, then you add the next 50 items to the adapter. This is a basic idea of how to do it.

Comment: Yes i have gone through this link bt i am not getting how to implement this concept on my project as data is loaded dynamically from webserver and i need to create pages dynamically.please guide